# Calculation in angular expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where I return a dollar amount and a discount percentage from an API for a number of products. I have an ng-repeat, where nn the UI, I want to show a discounted amount.

Something like:

```
{{this.amount * .(100 - this.discount)}}
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

Any advice?

Comment: Are both `this.amount` and `this.discount` defined? The use of `this` here is strange, usually in angular you add variables you want to `$scope`. E.g. in your controller: `$scope.amount = 5`, in your view: `{{amount}}` prints 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are both `this.amount` and `this.discount` defined? The use of `this` here is strange, usually in angular you add variables you want to `$scope`.

E.g.

In your controller: `$scope.amount = 5`

Then your view: `{{amount}}` prints 5.

---

Ignoring this the use of the period before the brackets is causing your issue, try:

```
{{this.amount * (100 - this.discount) / 100}}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid syntax: `{{amount * 0.(100 - discount)}}` (notice that 0)

Comment: Hi Mehul, I tried this  <div class="h3">{{item.cost * 0.(100 - item.discount)}}</div>, but it doesn't work. Here is my ng-repeat:   ng-repeat="item in results"

Comment: @cnak2 what do you get in console?

Answer (score 0):

remove this keyword. Instead, use scope variables to calculate the value.

```
{{amount * .(100 - discount)}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. That was just an example. I'm not actually using the this keyword. The actual line is:  <div class="h3">{{item.cost * 0.(100 - item.discount)}}</div>